# An error with dec to bin

Tags: binary, decimal

I have been debugging this function but I don't know why is it throwing 99 when I send 4 to the function.
This is a function to covert from decimal to binary.
Actually, I have tried to cout exp, res and the other variables in each step and then multiply them but I don't know. It doesn't make sense.

```
int DecToBinary(long num) {
    if(num == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    else if(num == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    int exp = 0;
    int res = 0;
    for (; num != 0; exp++){
        res = res+num%2*pow(10,exp);
        num = num/2;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Thank you guys.

Comment: if (num == 0) and else if (num == 0) is it a typo?

Comment: Yeah. I recently edited my thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(num == 0) {
    return 0;
}
else if(num == 0) {
    return 1;
}
```

You know the second branch will never be executed, right?

Furthermore:

```
pow(10,exp);
```

this yields a floating-point number. <s>Be prepared for rounding errors.</s> Even better: don't use `pow()` at all *(you don't need floating-point numbers for working with integers)*. Simply do the division step by step, accumulating the result in a variable.

```
int dec2bin(int n)
{
    int r = 0, tp = 1;
    while (n) {
        r += (n % 2) * tp;
        n >>= 1;
        tp *= 10;
    }
    return r;
}
```

Comment: Okay. But I'm not using exp(). Thank you!

Comment: @user2327884 Whatever, you're using `pow()`, that's what I meant. Math functions return `double` and `float`, and that's erroneous.

Comment: Oh I didn't know it. Thank you.

Comment: @user2327884 "I didn't know it" - **always** read the documentation of a function before using it. From the man page [(link)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pow.html), it should be clear that `pow()` returns `double`.